# File type support in Spring framework

Tags: spring, properties

Is it possible to instantiate a property of type `java.io.File` directly in the config?
Something like:

```
<property><file path="..." /></property>
```

A possible workaround may be to use a String property and while setting it, create the File instance. Is there a more direct way of achieving this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  Simply pass the name of the file as the value of the property:

```
<bean>
  <property name="myFile" value="path-to-file"/>
</bean>
```

Spring will automatically create an instance of java.io.File for you and inject it into your bean.

Answer (score 3):

Of course, just define it as `<bean/>` with `<constructor-arg/>`:

```
<property>
    <bean class="java.io.File">
        <constructor-arg value="/foo/bar.txt"/>
    </bean>
</property>
```

Comment: Thanks Tomasz! But as benw suggested below, this appears to a a mmore straightforward config - you see any issues with using that?

Comment: @Neel: if the syntax provided by *benw* works, I see nothing wrong with that (+1 to him). I didn't know Spring can convert `String` to file directly (!).